# Using std::sort in c++ with iterators and templates

Tags: c++, sorting, templates, iterator, std

I'm trying to get std::sort to work when using templates and a slightly complicated data structure. I can't seem to figure out why the following command causes errors

```
sort(graph->edge[0], graph->edge[(graph->E)-1], myComp<T>);
```

The data structures behind this are shown below.

```
template <typename T>
class Edge
{
    public:
    int src, dest;
    T weight;
};

template <typename T>
class Graph_krus
{
    public:
    int V, E;
    Edge<T>* edge;
};

template <typename T>
Graph_krus<T>* createGraph(int V, int E)
{
    Graph_krus<T>* graph = new Graph_krus<T>;
    graph->V = V;
    graph->E = E;
    graph->edge = new Edge<T>[E];
    return graph;
}

template <typename T>
bool myComp(Edge<T>* a, Edge<T>* b)
{
    bool greater = a->weight > b->weight;
    return greater;
}
```

This causes many build time errors. The errors from Xcode seem to be

> "No type named 'difference_type' in
>   'std::__1::iterator_traits >'"
>
> "No type named 'value_type'
>   in 'std::__1::iterator_traits >' "
>
> "Invalid operands to
>   binary expression ('Edge' and 'Edge') "
>
> "Cannot decrement
>   value of type 'Edge' "

and more

Comment: You need to pass to `std::sort` 2 iterators. But it seems that you are passing elements themselves. First and foremost why you don't use `std::vector` for `edge`?

Comment: `sort(graph->edge, graph->edge+graph->E, myComp<T>);` springs to mind, though I concur with Slava completely. I doubt there is any good reason why you should be doing *any* manual memory management in any of this.

Comment: @WhozCraig it still would not compile as `myComp` has wrong signature.

Comment: @SlavasupportsMonica Not the only thing that needs changing, obviously. That change is just to get an actual sequence iteration. The comparator will have to change as well.

Comment: "Ive tried putting both '*' and '&'" programming by guessing does not work

Comment: Haha no it certainly doesn't

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`std::sort` requires iterators or pointers. `graph->edge[0]` returns an `Edge` object reference not a pointer. You need to pass pointers instead:

```
std::sort(graph->edge, graph->edge + graph->E-1, myComp<T>);
```

Presuming you want to sort all the edges your second pointer needs to be one past the end of your list:

```
std::sort(graph->edge, graph->edge + graph->E, myComp<T>);
```

The next issue is that `myComp` needs to take references not pointers:

```
template <typename T>
bool myComp(const Edge<T>& a, const Edge<T>& b)
{
    bool greater = a.weight > b.weight;
    return greater;
}
```

As others have pointed out replacing your raw pointer arrays with `std::vector` would simplify your code and make it safer:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <memory>

template <typename T>
class Edge
{
    public:
    int src, dest;
    T weight;
};

template <typename T>
struct Graph_krus
{
    int V;
    std::vector<Edge<T>> edge;
};

template <typename T>
std::unique_ptr<Graph_krus<T>> createGraph(int V, int E)
{
    auto graph = std::make_unique<Graph_krus<T>>();
    graph->V = V;
    graph->edge.resize(E);
    return graph;
}
template <typename T>
bool myComp(const Edge<T>& a, const Edge<T>& b)
{
    bool greater = a.weight > b.weight;
    return greater;
}

int main()
{
    auto graph = createGraph<int>(1,1);
    std::sort(graph->edge.begin(), graph->edge.end(), myComp<int>);    
}
```